# How to setup redundant ejabberd servers?

Tags: xmpp, jabber, redundancy, ejabberd

I currently have an ejabberd server running at domain `A`. It has a bunch of users with accounts like `xyz@A`. I want to setup alternative servers so that if `A` is down, clients can transparently use alternative servers `B` and `C` (thus, while still using their `xyz@A` account).

The DNS part I think is pretty simple, I need to edit `A` zone file to add `SRV` records of the alternative servers like in this example (http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records#Example_3):

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 5222 server1.example.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 5222 server2.example.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 5222 server3.example.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 5222 server4.example.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 15 0 5222 backup.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 5269 server1.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 5269 server2.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 5269 server3.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 5269 server4.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 15 0 5269 backup.example.net.
```

What are the steps and specific configuration to setup the ejabberd servers on host `B` and `C` w.r.t authentification and chatrooms?

Although working redundant servers with the initial user db of `A` will be enough (I don't expect A to be down for a long time), ideally I think I should sync the user db between all 3 servers so that if someone makes an account on `B` while `A` is down can later log on `A` when it is back up. Does ejabberd provide a mechanism for that?

Comment: I will ask on serverfault...

Comment: Given that you haven't received answer for ejabberd I could recommend using Tigase XMPP Server - it supports clustering out of the box (see https://docs.tigase.net/tigase-server/8.0.0/Administration_Guide/html/#tigaseClustering) and it only requires enabling clustering mode - it will connect to the same database and allows authentication of the users. Completely separate issue is clustering/high availability of database but I would recommend using database specific solution for that.